# Autolayout frame x position incorrect when printed

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, ios-autolayout

I have UIView with subviews where i set autolayout like this:

```
    label1Container.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
    label1Container.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor),
    label1Container.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor),
    label2Container.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
    label2Container.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor),
    label2Container.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor),
    label2Container.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: label1Container.rightAnchor),
    label1Container.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: label2Container.widthAnchor),
```

then I try to get label2Container frame:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
            super.layoutIfNeeded()
            print("c1: \(label1Container.frame), c2: \(label2Container.frame)")
```

result is:

> c1: (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 128.0), c2: (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 128.0)

But on screen it renders well (purple).
[image]

How to get correct frame?

EDIT:
Ok, silly me I found that proper place to check frame is draw(frame: CGRect)

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer for future people with similar problems.

Answer (score 1):

Try like

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
   super.layoutSubviews()
   print("c1: \(label1Container.frame), c2: \(label2Container.frame)") 
}
```

It's `super.layoutSubviews()` not `super.layoutIfNeeded()`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, silly me I found that proper place to check frame is `draw(frame: CGRect)`